# How To Have My Character Turn When The Camera View Moves

Tags: unity, animation, camera, control

So I have recently finished animating my character, having it move with key presses and have applied a camera to it. But I am stumped on how to have the player turn when the camera view moves, and have them both in sink. I want to have this instead of using keys to turn because that can be very awkward and hard to control. I would really appreciate any help I can get on this, as it will allow me to finally finish my character.

Thanks, Nova

Comment: Perhaps adding a link to a YouTube video that shows what you need would help us help you here..

Comment: I don't have a video, but I can explaine it in a simpler way. Basically when you play a first person game to look around you move your mouse, and I would like my character to rotate with my mouse moments. Such as if I moved my mouse in turn moving my camera to look behind me my charter should rotate around to look in the direction of the camera.

Comment: You should edit the question with as much info as you can stuff in there :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO its done by attaching camera to the player as a child object, as the player rotate the camera will accordingly be rotated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a Matrix for your camera's rotation and position.

The solution would be to bind the camera's rotation matrix to your Character's rotation matrix, so whenever the camera rotates the character rotates as well.